# How to return value from call back?

Tags: javascript

When I use `alert()` or `console.log()` it works properly.

```js
function greeting(name) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

But when I use `return` it returns undefined

```js
function greeting(name) {
    let returnthis = `hello ${name}`
    return returnthis
  }


  
  function processUserInput(callback) {
    var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
    callback(name);
  }
  
  console.log(processUserInput(greeting));
```

Why is this happening?

How to return value?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/9936772) answer but can't understand.

Comment: simply add return `return callback(name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return callback also

```js
function greeting(name) {
  return `hello ${name}`
}



function processUserInput(callback) {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  return callback(name);
}

console.log(processUserInput(greeting));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `processUserInput` returns nothing. Do:

```
  return callback(name);
```